# Select documents where all values in an array field exist in another array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wasn't quite sure how to title this!

So I have an array of product IDs

```
var productIds = [139,72,73,1,6]
```

And a bunch of customer documents in MongoDB

```
{
    name: 'James',
    products: [ 73, 139 ],
    _id: 5741cff3f08e992598d0a39b
}

{
    name: 'John',
    products: [ 72, 99 ],
    _id: 5741d047f08e992598d0a39e
}
```

I would like to find customers when all of their products appear in the array of product IDs (productIds)

I tried:

```
'products' : {
    '$in': productIds
}
```

But that returns John, even though 99 doesn't exist in the list of product IDs

I also tried:

```
'products' : {
    '$all': productIds
}
```

Which returns nothing because none of the customer have ALL the products

Is there a way to achieve what I need in a single query or am I going to have to do some post query processing?

I also tried

```
'products': {
    '$in': productIds,
    '$not': {
        '$nin': productIds
    }
}
```

but this also seems to return customers when not all product IDs match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method and the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator. In your [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expressions you need to use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) in order to check if all the elements in the "products" array are in "productIds". This is because you cannot use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/in/) in the conditional expression

```
var productIds = [139,72,73,1,6];
db.customers.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$setIsSubset": [ "$products", productIds ] },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }} 
])
```