# In Mongo, how would I match all items of collection against a larger array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Let's say I have 3 items in a collection:

```
[
    {
        id: 'a',
        items: [1, 2, 3]
    }, {
        id: 'b',
        items: [4, 5, 6]
    }, {
        id: 'c',
        items: [7, 8, 9]
    }
]
```

On the JavaScript code side, all I have is an array `[5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8]`. How would I compose my query to select only the 2nd object from the collection since my array has all the elements (4, 5 and 6) of its `items` array?

Comment: Is pure javascript solution acceptable in this case?

Comment: I'm looking for a Mongo query, because the set I gave is tiny and db has millions of docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select documents where all values in an array field exist in a larger array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376408/select-documents-where-all-values-in-an-array-field-exist-in-a-larger-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mongoDB **[Aggregation Set Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/)** you can filter your array. First find out intersection of given array with actual database array and after that used set equals method. check below query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$project": {
    "checkAllElem": {
        "$setEquals": [{
            "$setIntersection": ["$items", [5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8]]
        }, "$items"]
    },
    "items": 1
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
    "checkAllElem": true
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yogesh! This is perfect :)